# Endless failures of Firebase authentication

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

My app fails on authentication new users while registering. The application is connected to Google Firebase and nothing seems to be done wrong with it. Code seems also alright, it displays no errors and I checked everything 10000000 times. Everything needed is already imported. When I try to register new user an error appears which says: "An internal error has occured. [Access Not Configured. Google Identity Toolkit API has not been used in project (here is 12-digit project number) before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting console.developers.google.com/apis/api/… project number) then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.] I set up authentication yesterday so I don't know what to do...

```
public class RegisterUserActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //DECLARE FIELDS
    EditText userEmailCreateEditText, userPassWordCreateEditText;
    LinearLayout createAccountBtn;
    //FIREBASE AUTHENTICATION ID
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    //PROGRESS DIALOG
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_user);
        //ASSIGN ID'S
        userEmailCreateEditText = ( EditText ) findViewById(R.id.emailRegisterEditText);
        userPassWordCreateEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordRegisterEditText);
        createAccountBtn = ( LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.createAccountSubmitBtn);
        //PROGRESS DIALOG INSTANCE
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        //FIREBASE INSTANCE
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                //CHECK USER
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if( user != null )
                {
                    Intent moveToHome = new Intent(RegisterUserActivity.this, Home.class);
                    moveToHome.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity( moveToHome );
                }
            }
        };
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        //CREATE ON CLICK LISTENER
        createAccountBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mProgressDialog.setTitle("Create Account");
                mProgressDialog.setMessage("Wait while the account is being created..");
                mProgressDialog.show();
                createUserAccount();
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
    //LOGIC FOR CREATING THE USER ACCOUNT
    private void createUserAccount() {
        String emailUser, passUser;
        emailUser = userEmailCreateEditText.getText().toString().trim();
        passUser = userPassWordCreateEditText.getText().toString().trim();
        if( !TextUtils.isEmpty(emailUser) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(passUser))
        {
            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailUser, passUser).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if( task.isSuccessful() )
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterUserActivity.this, "Account created Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                        Intent moveToHome = new Intent(RegisterUserActivity.this, Home.class);
                        moveToHome.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity( moveToHome );
                    }else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterUserActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                        task.getException().getMessage();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you did what it said and enabled Google auth in the dashboard for your project?

Comment: Sure I did, I set enabled both email/password and Google authentication.

Comment: You might want to contact Firebase support so they can diagnose.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Answer (score 0):

The `project_id` in your Android app's `google-services.json` file should be the same as the Firebase Console project for which you enabled Google Sign In Authentication. Try re-download google-services.json from Firebase Console, and re-build your Android app.